# Подсчет строк в БД

Tags: c#, sql

Как я могу подсчитать количество строк в которых `tmstmp=0`?
Пытался через `numRows = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());`
Но получаю значение 178, а у меня таких строк 6000

```
public static void IMG()
{
  using (SqlConnection connection = GetConection())
   {
     string query = "SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE tmstmp=@t";
     SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
     command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@t", "0");
     connection.Open();
     numRows = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
     MessageBox.Show(numRows.ToString());
     using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
      {
        .....
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: _Но получаю значение 178_ - проверьте значение первого столбца первой строки :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для подсчета количества строк используйте функцию [Count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms175997(v=sql.120).aspx).
Тогда ваш запрос будет выглядеть следующим образом

```
string query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Table] WHERE tmstmp=@t"
```

Answer (score 3):

Просто: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Table] WHERE tmstmp=0`, но запрос вернет число и кажись на этом `command.ExecuteReader()` будет фейл.